# Dockerized Airflow couldn't run Spark jobs

Tags: java, apache-spark, docker-compose, dockerfile, airflow

I tried to run a Pyspark task through executing `python /myfile.py` via BashOperator on Airflow but received the following error:

```
[2023-09-19, 23:28:26 UTC] {subprocess.py:86} INFO - Output:
[2023-09-19, 23:28:35 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 68: ps: command not found
[2023-09-19, 23:28:35 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
[2023-09-19, 23:28:35 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
```

I think it is because the java environment is not recognized.
I'm using the following Dockerfile extension in addition to the docker-compose.yaml provided by Airflow.

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.7.1
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         openjdk-11-jre-headless \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER airflow
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark==2.1.3
RUN pip install apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark
```

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: could you explain why to use `BashOperator` if you need to run `python` script?

Comment: Because of separation of concern, it's not a function but rather a pyspark job. I have it stored somewhere else as a .py file.

Comment: don't understand. could you show `myfile.py`?

Comment: by the way could you add `dag` file with `BashOperator`?